# Django Python Foreign Key issue

Tags: python, django, view, foreign-keys

I am showing "well" information linked to a specific project successfully based on well_id
When I try to show drilling_tools in a similar fashion I get an error.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in my views?

```
def well_show(request, well_id):
    well = Well.objects.get(pk=well_id)
    drilling_tools = DrillingTool.objects.get(pk=well_id)
    return render(request, 'geodata/well_show.html', {'well': well, 'drilling_tools': drilling_tools})
```

Comment: Please share the error trace.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Create a new question instead of editing your old one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead if they are related:

```
def well_show(request, well_id):
    well = Well.objects.get(pk=well_id)
    drilling_tools = DrillingTool.objects.filter(well__id=well_id)
    return render(request, 'geodata/well_show.html', {'well': well, 'drilling_tools': drilling_tools})
```

---

Your code isn't working because the `well.id` can differ from the `drilling_tools.id`. They are in a separate table after all, and some funky *(but easily preventable)* race conditions can occur.

Comment: This worked, but now I can't iterate over multiple tools. It only works for one tool, but I have several  tools belonging to each well.